# Transfinite series: Uncountable sums

Tags: analysis, real-analysis

If you sum an expression over an uncountable set
$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x)$, then do we need $f(x)=0$ on all but a countable subset in order for the sum to have a finite value?

If not can you give an example of a function everywhere nonzero that has a transfinite sum with a finite value?

Possible keywords: Transseries, Écalle–Borel Summation, analyzable function

[Transseries for beginners](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4877), GA Edgar, 2009

Comment: I realise odds are you'll never see this, but by any chance do you happen to be poster from this [thread](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/uncountable-sum.328751/)?  Be seeing you...

Answer (score 10):

**HINT**

Given $\varepsilon>0$, can you measure the set $\{x:f(x)>\varepsilon\}$?

---

*Edit:* Giving some background to the somewhat short hint.

Suppose $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, and let $f$ be a *non-negative* function defined on $E$. The usual definition of the expression $\sum_{x\in E}f(x)$ is given by
$$  
\sum_{x\in E}f(x) =\sup_{F\subset E,\,|F|<\infty}\sum_{x\in F}f(x) \tag{1}
$$
i.e. we take supremum over finite sets.

Now, let us choose $\varepsilon>0$ and consider the set 
$$E_\varepsilon = \{x\in E :f(x)>\varepsilon\}.$$
This set must be finite in order for the sum in (1) to be finite, because otherwise we may for each positive integer $n$ choose subsets $F_n\subset E_\varepsilon$ such that $|F_n|=n$ and then $$\sum_{x\in E}f(x)\ge \sum_{x\in F_n}f(x)>\sum_{F_n}\varepsilon =n\varepsilon.$$

Since $$\bigcup_{\varepsilon>0}
 E_\varepsilon =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_{1/n} =\{x\in E:f(x)>0\}$$
the conclusion follows.

**Note:** I added the assumption $f\ge0$. In fact I do not think there is a reasonable definition for conditional convergence of this kind.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my stupidity! The working day must have been too long.

Comment: @Alex Bartel: I have been there too :)

Comment: For the rest of us, can somebody expand on the answer?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I agree to your point, the hint was perhaps a bit short! I hope you like my update better...

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I am glad to hear that.