# Is every Hilbert space an $L^2$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $H$ be any Hilbert space. Must there exist a measure space $(X,\scr{M},\mu)$ such that we have a Hilbert space isomorphism:
$$H\cong L^2(\mu)$$

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. If $\kappa>0$ is the (Hilbert) dimension of $H$, then you can take for $\mu$ the counting measure on $\kappa$ and then it's easy to see that $H\cong L^2(\mu)=\ell^2(\kappa)$.

If $\kappa=0$, then take any $\mu$ such that $\mu(X)=\infty$ for any nonempty set $X$. Then $L^2(\mu)=\{0\}$.

Comment: $H\cong L^2(\mu)\cong \ell^2(k)$?

Comment: The last one is equality, not isomorphism. The congruence follows from the fact that two Hilbert spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic (which is immediate from the definition). I believe it is entirely elementary, calling it a theorem is a gross overstatement. Basically the only things this argument uses are the definitions and the fact that every Hilbert space has a (Hilbert) basis.

Comment: It is true for separable Hilbert space. Is it true that every Hilbert space $H$ is the same as $L^2(\mu)$?

Comment: The same how? This is more or less what this question is about...