# What is the sum of all real numbers from $0$ to $1$?

Tags: summation, real-numbers

I wanted to know the approximate sum of real numbers from 0 to 1.

Please tell me how we can find it.

Comment: there are infinitely many(uncountable) numbers greater than $1/2.$

Comment: It is difficult to take a sum of an uncountable number of numbers.  Even if you restricted the sum to positive rational numbers in top half of the interval, you would get an infinite result.

Comment: Something like $\int_{x=0}^1 x$ is more appropriate, I think.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The sum diverges:
$$\large\sum_{a\in[0,1]}a=\sup_{\substack{\text{finite}\\S\subset[0,1]}}\sum_{a\in S}a\geq \sup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\geq\sup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)=\infty$$

Observe this definition from Folland's real analysis book:

> [image]

Comment: Under this definition with $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in X$, we get $\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \infty$ whenever there are uncountably many $x \in X$ such that $f(x)>0$.

Comment: Indeed, that's Folland's next statement :) ([image link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IEhSx.png))

Comment: Interesting.  I have never seen such a definition.  Perhaps it is only useful for that fact itself...which can be interpeted as saying that the sum is always infinity except at times when standard definitions of sums apply. =) Yet your quote says "We shall occasionally encounter uncountable sums," I wonder when such things would actually be encountered.

Comment: @Michael Re: *I wonder when such things would actually be encountered.* I think that this might be a good question on the main site. (However, there were already some posts about this type of sum, so if you decide to post a separate question about this, you should search first.) I do not know where they are used in Folland's book.

Comment: One application I have seen is the definition of the Hilbert space $\ell_2(A)$. If you already learned about Hilbert spaces, you have certainly seen $\ell_2=\ell_2(\mathbb N)$, where the inner product is given by $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum\limits_{i\in\mathbb N} x_iy_i$. If we allow summation over arbitrary sets, then we can define $\ell_2(A)$ using almost the same construction; in this case, the inner product will be $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum\limits_{i\in A} x_iy_i$. It can be shown that this is indeed a Hilbert space and that every space is isomorphic to $\ell_2(A)$ for some set $A$.

Comment: So this is, in some sense, a classification of all Hilbert spaces. This result can be found, for example, in Chapter 13 Roman's  Advanced Linear Algebra" or in Chapter 9 of Dixmier's General Topology. You should probably be able [to find](https://books.google.com/books?q="every+hilbert+space"+isomorphic+"l2") some [other places](https://books.google.com/books?q="every+hilbert+space"+isomorphic+cardinality) where this result is shown.

Comment: @Michael Only after posting the above comments I have found this question which asks exactly about applications of uncountable sums: [Does uncountable summation, with a finite sum, ever occur in mathematics?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70194/does-uncountable-summation-with-a-finite-sum-ever-occur-in-mathematics)

Answer (score 6):

The sum is infinite. We don't really have a good definition for $$\sum_{x\in [0,1]}x,$$
But it seems reasonable that he following relation should hold for any proposed definition.
$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb [0,1]} x\geq \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{n}=\infty.$$

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Comment: I will not downvote, but of course $\sum_{x \in [0,1]} x$ has no meaning since we cannot sum over an uncountably infinite set.

Comment: Good point. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Michael: I have seen a commonly accepted definition of such a sum as long as every term of the sum is non-negative. Please see my answer for example.

Comment: @Michael: See for example [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers) and other posts [linked to it](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20661) for some further references.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks.  That post seems along the same lines as my comment to Zev's answer, though his answer contains the definiton that can be used.