# A question about an uncountable summation.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The sum of an uncountable number of positive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20661/the-sum-of-an-uncountable-number-of-positive-numbers)

Consider $\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} a_{\lambda}$ . Here all $a_\lambda $ is non-negative. 
Then I want to prove that if $\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} a_{\lambda} < \infty $ then there exists at most countable set $ \Lambda_0 \subset \Lambda$ such that $\lambda \notin \Lambda_0 \Rightarrow a_{\lambda}=0.$

(This means that if the summation converges then there are only at most countable $a_i$'s such that $a_i \neq 0)$

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/70194) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/106102).

Comment: @t.b.: I had a hunch this was a duplicate, but I just woke up. Answering was the simpler solution than searching for a duplicate... :-P

Comment: I remember this [Transfinite series: Uncountable sums](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13781/transfinite-series-uncountable-sums). The question appears very frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Given $\varepsilon>0$, can you measure the set $\{\lambda:a_\lambda>\varepsilon\}$?

---

> Giving some background to the somewhat short hint.
>
>  Suppose $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, and let
>  $\lambda\mapsto a_\lambda$ be a *non-negative* function defined on $E$. The
>  usual definition of the expression $\sum_{\lambda\in E}a_\lambda$ is given by
>  $$\sum_{\lambda\in E}a_\lambda =\sup_{F\subset E,\,|F|<\infty}\sum_{\lambda\in F}a_\lambda \tag{1}$$
>  i.e. we take supremum over finite sets. 
>
>  Now, let us choose $\varepsilon>0$ and consider the set 
>  $$E_\varepsilon = \{\lambda\in E :a_\lambda>\varepsilon\}.$$ This set
>  must be finite in order for the sum in (1) to be finite, because
>  otherwise we may for each positive integer $n$ choose subsets
>  $F_n\subset E_\varepsilon$ such that $|F_n|=n$ and then
>  $$\sum_{\lambda\in E}a_\lambda\ge \sum_{\lambda\in F_n}a_\lambda>\sum_{F_n}\varepsilon =n\varepsilon.$$
>  
>  Since $$\bigcup_{\varepsilon>0}  E_\varepsilon =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_{1/n} =\{\lambda\in E:a_\lambda>0\}$$ the conclusion follows.
>  
>  **Remark:** If we exclude the assumption $a_\lambda\ge0$. I do not think there is a reasonable definition for conditional convergence of this kind.

Comment: How do you like the hidden text?

Comment: @Ｊ.Ｍ. First now I noted your question. Thanks for providing the hiding feature to the hint. Better late than never.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the series is convergent.

There cannot be more than finitely many elements larger than $\frac12$, as that would contradict convergence; and there cannot be more than finitely many elements larger than $\frac14$, for the same reason...

In particular for every $n\in\mathbb N$ there are only finitely many $a_\lambda$ such that $\frac1{2^n}<a_\lambda$.

Now we have a countable union of finite sets of nonzero elements, so this is $\Lambda_0$, the rest has to be zero since all the elements are non-negative.